# Custom annotation processor - Java

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have created a custom annotation and annotation processor using Abstract Processor. Which means I want to do annotation processing a before compile time.
I exported my custom annotation and processor as a Jar and trying to use it with a simple java test program.
I am sure that at compile time it finds my java processor class but somehow I am not getting o/p that I am expecting on console.
Below is the code of the process method in my processor.

Also, I am purposely using `@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)` so that I get a version warning which confirms that when I execute a test class it finds my annotation processor.

Here is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/yogeshdixit41/CustomAnnotationandProcessorJava) to my full project which also has the packaged Jar that I have created.

```
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.NOTE, "Hello compile time message");

    for (Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Contract.class)) {
        if(elem.getKind() != ElementKind.METHOD)
        {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.NOTE, "Error");
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println("Hello ... Inside for ");
        Contract contract = elem.getAnnotation(Contract.class);
        String message = "annotation found in " + elem.getSimpleName()
                       + " with complexity " + contract.pre_cond();
        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.NOTE, message);
    }
    return true; // no further processing of this annotation type
}
```

Below is the test class that I am using,

```
import annotations.Contract;

public class AnnotationTest {


public AnnotationTest()
{
    super();
}

@Contract(pre_cond = { "var > 0" })
public static void testMethod(int var)
{
    System.out.println("hello1");
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    testMethod(1);
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

I am compiling the above test class using `javac -cp newcontractlib.jar AnnotationTest.java` command and I just get the version warning and no messages from my process method.

Answer (score 1):

How are you invoking javac, is it through Maven? I think you need to enable debug logging (append `-X` to your Maven invocation) in order to see diagnostics of kind NOTE.

You also can use the compiler options `-XprintProcessorInfo` and `-XprintRounds` to see whether your processor kicks in.